# jQuery ajax jsonp unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the data from third party http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?Appid=APPID&query=SEARCH_TERM&sources=Web&web.count=40&web.offset=41.

so i just used jsonp to get the data.I got the 200 status code.But i didn't get the resultant data on success.I also tried the callback it doesn't work.

Attached my source code :

```
    $.ajax({
      type : "GET",
      url : "http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?Appid=APPID&query=SEARCH_TERM&sources=Web&web.count=40&web.offset=41",
      dataType : "jsonp",
      success : function(data){
          console.log(data);
      },
      error : function(error) {
          console.log(error);
      }
    });
```

Error return in console :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

How can i solve this issue...

Comment: it doesn't looks like the said api is supporting jsonp

Answer (score 0):

That site doesnt support the jsonp. If it does, it should return the response with a call back function bind in it.
ex:

```
callbackFun({"SearchResponse":{"Version":"2.2","Query":{"SearchTerms":"SEARCH_TERM"},"Errors":[{"Code":1002,"Message":"Parameter has invalid value.","Parameter":"SearchRequest.AppId","Value":"APPID","HelpUrl":"http:\/\/msdn.microsoft.com\/en-us\/library\/dd251042.aspx"}]}})
```

**EDIT**
If you want to get that response to your client side. Make your server act as a proxy to that site. (Make an HTTP GET call from your server). And your client code will communicate to your server for the third party site's data.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.Is any other option have to render the data from the third party without jsonp.

Answer (score 0):

your reponse seem to be valid,please try this

```
$.ajax({
          type : "GET",
          url : "http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?Appid=APPID&query=SEARCH_TERM&sources=Web&web.count=40&web.offset=41",
          dataType : "json",
          success : function(data){
              console.log(data);
          },
          error : function(error) {
              console.log(error);
          }
        });
```